# Is it possible to de-initialize a jQuery plugin after it's been initialised?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I'm looking for a way to de-initialise a jQuery plug-in after it's already been used on an element. It's for a slider, that after a certain action or after a certain situation arrises looses all the behavior applied to it byt he plugin.

Is this possible?

Comment: It depends on the plugin. Which one are you using?

Comment: It is the Flexslider plug-in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's only *really* possible if the plug-in provides a means of doing so. A well-written one should, usually by providing a "method" called `destroy`. For instance, in jQuery UI, you can remove a datepicker from an element like this:

```
$("selector").datepicker("destroy");
```

If the plug-in doesn't provide a means of doing it, it gets a bit tricky. You could clone the element without cloning events and data, and then replace the original with the clone, but that's unlikely to be effective in all cases and really is a hack workaround more than anything else.

Comment: it stands to reason, then, that one could actually write a prototype function designed to destroy any $.fn.namespace, doesn't it?

Comment: @Kristian Destroying the namespace, and destroying the modifications that plugin made are *very* different.

Comment: @Kristian: Not following you. Removing a plug-in's effects on an element (and possibly its descendants) has little if anything to do with the `$.fn` object. When a plug-in is initialized on an element, typically it will add attributes, data, events, possibly new descendant elements (or ancestors, sometimes), possibly hide some existing descendants (or the element as a whole), etc., etc.

Comment: OK you both make a fine point there. typically what people mean to do is simply unregister the namespaces that have been taken up by the plugin. but if you're going the extent of cleaning up anything the plugin changed during init, then yes, you're right. a full-on deconstructor is required.

Comment: @Kristian: I believe that's the OP's question. Not about removing the plug-in from jQuery, but about undoing its effects on specific elements.

Comment: Thanks for the useful discussion. Perhaps one could create a function that records the effects of a plug-in and store data about what has changed in order to reverse them? Would that be possible?

Comment: @shrewdbeans: *Possibly.* It would be very difficult and would require getting into undocumented areas of jQuery, and it would require assuming that the plug-in *only* did things via jQuery. There's no cross-browser way to know that something's done `addEventListener`, for instance, but if you dive deep into jQuery you can find information related to its `on` mechanism for adding handlers. In most cases, I think you'd be better off examining the source of the plug-in instead.